# avoid special caractere when creating folder via ftp

Tags: php

I am creating a folder on a server via FTP, but when the folder name contains special characters, the special characters are replaced by other characters.

```
$ftp_server = "FTP SERVER";
$ftp_user_name = 'username'; /* username */
$ftp_user_pass = 'password'; /* password */
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, "folder/");


$dir1 = "folder/".$_POST['name'];

if (ftp_mkdir($ftp_conn, $dir) 
  {
  echo "successfully created $dir";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Erreur Création $dir";
  }

// `close conection */
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the better solution is to remove special char before the folder creation.

```
$name = clean($_POST['name']);

$ftp_server = "FTP SERVER";
$ftp_user_name = 'username'; /* username */
$ftp_user_pass = 'password'; /* password */
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, "folder/");


$dir1 = "folder/".$name;

if (ftp_mkdir($ftp_conn, $dir)
  {
  echo "successfully created $dir";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Erreur Création $dir1";
  }

// `close conection */
ftp_close($ftp_conn);

function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); 
   $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); 

   return preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string); 
}
```

Comment: can i keep the character and display as it is on the folder ?

Comment: char will be removed